# Proper visualization of the label name

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

How can I properly structure the label name of the generated graph? The code used in generating the graph is written below:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
feat_import = pd.Series(importance, new_data.columns[0:len(new_data.columns)-2])
plt.plot(feat_import, 'r')
plt.title('Best Feature Selection')
plt.ylabel('Importance')
plt.xlabel('Available features')
plt.legend([ 'importance to dependent variable'], loc='upper right')
```

The generated result is this:
[image]

I underlined with green color where I am having the issue.

One of the best ways will be to show the label name vertically rather than the horizontal display shown above. Please, how can I achieve that?

Comment: The correct way: `feat_import.plot(rot=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the label names of the horizontal axis can be done via:

`plt.xticks(rotation = 90) # Rotates X-Axis Ticks by 90-degrees`

Minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
feat_import = pd.Series(data=range(10), index=['abc' * (i+1) for i in range(10)])
plt.plot(feat_import, 'r')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]